# Implication when a simple connected graph is completed

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

I am struggling to prove this.

Let G be a simple connected graph.

$ |E(H)| \neq 2$  for all subgraphs $H$ of $G\Longrightarrow$ G is a completed graph

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick distinct vertices $u,v.$ Since $G$ is connected, $u$ and $v$ are connected by some path $u\sim v_1\sim \dots\sim  v_k=v.$ For each $1\leq i\leq k-1,$ if $u\sim v_i$ then since the subgraph $u,v_i,v_{i+1}$ cannot have only the two edges $u\sim v_i$ and $v_i\sim v_{i+1},$ we must have $u\sim v_{i+1}.$ So by induction, $u\sim v_k=v.$ This proves that $G$ is complete.

Comment: Wow thats good. Thank you alot